# Livestream with crtmpserver - I can't find the live file

Tags: rtmp, rtmps, rtmpd

I use [crtmpserver](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/crtmpserver.1.html) to make my [RTMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol) server. I use Adobe [Flash Media Live Encoder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash_Media_Live_Encoder) 3.2 to publish the livestream to the server. It is OK. I use a webflash player to receive the live stream. It is OK.

Now, I want to find the live file in the server, but I can't find the file. Which folder is the livestream?

Answer (score 1):

**If you want to stream a .flv file:**

In every crtmpserver application there is a property called `mediaFolder` that by default refers to folder `media`.

```
mediaFolder="./media",
```

Then the streaming URL of the file is as:

```
rtmp://<server IP address>/<application name>/<file name>
```

**If you want to stream a live stream:**

When you define an stream acceptor in the acceptors section, you can specify the name of the stream by `localStreamName` as:

```
{
    ip="0.0.0.0",
    port=9005,
    protocol="inboundTcpTs",
    localStreamName="tcpchan5"
},
```

Then the URL of this stream is as:

```
rtmp://<server IP address>/<application name>/tcpchan5
```

To receive the input stream and feed the RTMP server, you may use [FFmpeg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFmpeg):

```
ffmpeg -i <input_stream> -vcodec libx264 -s 320x240 -vb 512k -async 1 -acodec libvo_aacenc -ab 32k -ac 1 -f mpegts tcp://<server IP address>:<server feed port>
```

For example:

```
ffmpeg -i udp://224.11.11.11:2000 -vcodec libx264 -s 320x240 -vb 512k -async 1 -acodec libvo_aacenc -ab 32k -ac 1 -f mpegts tcp://127.0.0.1:9000
```

Comment: is there any possibility to store the live video file in crtmpserver @Sajad

Comment: No crtmpserver can't do that. If just you want to store live stream you can use ffmpeg tool; and if you want time shifting capability live channels; you can use ffserver tool.

Comment: ohh .. can we integrate that ffmpeg tool to your crtmpserver? @Sajad

Comment: You can write a linux shell script to receive and record input stream directly as the stream is sent to the crtmpserver. Please note that input stream must be transcoded to MPEG4 (preferentially h264) to be shown on crtmpserver. Then you can duplicate transcoded stream one to feed the rtmp server and other to save on file.

Comment: No sir... this is not typical here.